# Configure Log4J with Java

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

From the Log4J web site I found that I can configure it with Java code without properties file. Is there any basic example how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

### In Log4J 1.x :

Use `BasicConfigurator.configure();`

Taken from [Log4J manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html):

*The log4j environment is fully configurable programmatically. However, it is far more flexible to configure log4j using configuration files. Currently, configuration files can be written in XML or in Java properties (key=value) format.
Let us give a taste of how this is done with the help of an imaginary application MyApp that uses log4j.*

```
import com.foo.Bar;

 // Import log4j classes.
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

 public class MyApp {

   // Define a static logger variable so that it references the
   // Logger instance named "MyApp".
   static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.
     BasicConfigurator.configure();

     logger.info("Entering application.");
     Bar bar = new Bar();
     bar.doIt();
     logger.info("Exiting application.");
   }
 }
```

Class `Bar` is as follows:

```
package com.foo;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Bar {
  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Bar.class);

  public void doIt() {
    logger.debug("Did it again!");
  }
}
```

*The invocation of the `BasicConfigurator.configure` method creates a rather simple log4j setup. This method is hardwired to **add to the root logger a ConsoleAppender**. The output will be **formatted using a PatternLayout** set to the **pattern "%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n**".
Note that **by default, the root logger is assigned to Level.DEBUG**.
The output of MyApp is:*

```
0    [main] INFO  MyApp  - Entering application.
36   [main] DEBUG com.foo.Bar  - Did it again!
51   [main] INFO  MyApp  - Exiting application.
```

### In Log4J 2.x :

The example would be the same but **without the call **`BasicConfigurator.configure();` and also `Logger.getLogger` would be `LogManager.getLogger`